# Are there any currently updated GUI LESS auto-compilers?

Tags: css, windows, less

LESS is becoming a graveyard of abandoned auto-compile apps. I've moved from SimpLESS, to WinLess, to Prepros, to Koala. All of them appear to have been abandoned by their developers and have not been updated in a very long time. At the moment, Koala will do because it utilizes the highest version of LESS out of all the apps (yet is still out of date), but it is missing some very important features (specifically, deep include monitoring).

Is there a LESS compiler out there that is up to date and has not been abandoned? I'm looking for a GUI-based compiler that watches files (and imported files) for changes and automatically compiles the CSS on change.

Comment: Grunt http://www.wearecube.ch/from-less-to-css-with-grunt-js/

Comment: @Christina I am looking for a GUI that can be configured by a non-technical CSS dev and watches deeply imported files.

Comment: @Harry That is command-line and not GUI. It doesn't watch imported files for changes.

Comment: Yeah, I get you. I use CodeKit as I am right brained mostly https://incident57.com/codekit/versionhistory.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing less support for stand alone auto-compilers is because `grunt` and `gulp` provide great resources for managing build processes.  Including precompiling `CSS`

Both task managers can watch for changes `less` changes and auto compile.

Here is a basic example of **`gulp`** that would only compile and watch less files in the 'less/' directory.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');

// Task to compile Less
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src(['app/css/style.less'])
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/build'))
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('less/*.less', ['styles']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['less', 'watch']);
```

[**A nice tutorial to get you started.**](http://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp)

Gulp and Grunt both use node so you will have to do a couple installs, but it is straightforward and creates a very fast seemless build process.